# Where can I find LPJ Design's alternate gun rules for Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, product-identification, gunslinger

From [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/7683/3548):

> Your main problem is that the Gunslinger is gimped by the awful Pathfinder gun rules. It will never have comparable damage to other characters. Consider getting your DM to allow better firearm rules, they exist in the Pathfinder Freeport Companion and Adamant Entertainment's Tome of Secrets, and here's a great free set of gun rules (I wrote) for Pathfinder from LPJ Design via RPGNow.

The link in that answer is dead. Where are LPJ Design's alternate gun rules for Pathfinder available now?

Comment: I have updated the original answer with a link to my copy of those rules.

Answer (score 3):

According to the newly [updated answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/7683/3548) that @mxyzplk has provided, you can find those rules [here](https://mxyzplk.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/gunpowder-in-golarion1.pdf). The original link to LPJ Design's rules, linking to RPGNow died and the rules are unable to be found on the site currently. The rules at the above link, while not as graphically designed, are reportedly the same. Please see the linked answer for more details.